# protractor using xpath //*[contains('text')] error element not visible

Tags: xpath, protractor

Hi I have this element from a dropdown menu I try to select:

```
<div class="tt-suggestion tt-selectable">
  <strong class="tt-highlight">Auto Customer</strong>
</div>
```

If I use `element(by.xpath("//strong[contains(text(),'Auto Customer')]")).click();` I can select it no problem. But if I use `element(by.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Auto Customer')]")).click();` I get "Failed: element not visible"

Can someone explain this to me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Because the `*` in `//*[contains(text(),'Auto Customer')]` means any tag, not only the `strong` Tag. But `//strong[contains(text(),'Auto Customer')]` must be `strong` Tag.

`//*[contains(text(),'Auto Customer')]` should find more then one elements on page, and the first one is not visible.  You can try this xpath in Chrome DevTool's `Element` Tab to see how many elements it can find and the first one is visible or not.